# Images in Extbase - Fluid

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase

I have an standard image upload in TYPO3 Backend, that allows more than 1 image upload.

So I have an image database field with data like that: "image1.jpg,image2.jpg".

In Frontend, I can explode the field, send the array to fluid, and output it in a fluid:for each like that:

```
<f:image src="uploads/tx_myext/{image}"  />
```

First question is: is there maybe some fancy new Extbase or Fluid Magic, that creates image objects right from database?

Second question: if I have a huge 2MB image and make a fluid:image output with width=100, is it just scaled in browser, or is it really downsized using ImageMagick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Comma list to array:

Unfortunately as I can see in Extbase 4.7 there is still no ViewHelper for iterating comma separated strings. You have two options: write custom ViewHelper or stay with the way you are using.

TIP: To avoid passing additional params (especially when you have many comma separated fields there and/or using many `Partials` for rendering the view) I'm adding a **public** field to my model. Without representation in TCA it will be considered as *transient*,  ie:

```
/**
 * @var array
 */
public $imagesArray;
```

and then just filling it in controller right before assigning so I can access it as `{project.imagesArray}` in the view:

```
public function showAction(Tx_Myext_Domain_Model_Project $project) {
    $project->imagesArray = explode(',', $project->getImage());
    $this->view->assign('project', $project);
}
```

view

```
<f:for each="{project.imagesArray}" as="image">
    <f:image src="uploads/tx_myext/{image}" width="200" height="200m" alt="" />
</f:for>
```

Most probably you are using quite similar approach...

#### Image resizing:

It's easiest just to ... check. `ImageMagick` hashes the name of the resized image and stores it in the temp folder by default, so if in code preview you see the path like: `typo3temp/pics/cd27baa408.jpg` instead of `uploads/tx_myext/photo123.jpg` that means it was converted with IM. And yes, image `ViewHelper` uses the IM.

You can even add perform simple calculations by giving value as `width="200m"` or `width="200c"` from viewhelper's phpdoc: *[See imgResource.width for possible options](http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/core-documentation/doc_core_tsref/4.7.0/view/1/5/#id551989)*

Comment: Thanks a lot for verifying my first approach, wasn't sure if that is to complicated. I could not check ImageMagick, as I had not coded it yet - and was thinking about some oldschool cObj->IMAGE Code as well.

Comment: How about JSWindow for image click-enlarge?

Answer (score 0):

Now I created a ViewHelper in Typo3 Forge as I think processing of images as they come from database would be quite usefull.

And I added imageLinkWrap for JS Window.

http://forge.typo3.org/issues/46218